# Why is true && false equal to 1 in C++?

Tags: c++, boolean, logical-operators, operator-precedence, boolean-logic

I was playing around with booleans and ended up with this line of code:

`std::cout << true && false;`

which, for some reason, produces `1`. How is this possible, if `&&` requires both sides to be true, in order to produce `1`?

Comment: Because its actually seen by the compiler as (std::cout << true ) then the function result is ANDed with false and the result discarded. Use Brackets to avoid operator precedence issues https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence eg std::cout<< (true && false)

Comment: IMO, the design decision regarding the precedence of the C << and >> operators was a sad mistake.

Comment: The precedence of `<<` operator is greater than that of `&&` so the expression is same as `(std::cout << true) && false` and it's valid because `std::cout` which is `std::basic_ostream` object has a bool conversion operator. So essentially it boils down to `static_cast<bool>((std::cout << true)) && false`

Comment: @YvesDaoust -- in C, the precedence does what's expected. The problem in C++ is that `<<` and `>>` are **overloaded** for use with streams, and the precedence that works in mixed arithmetic/logical expressions doesn't work well for stream operations.

Comment: @PeteBecker: no, you don't get it. a << b + c should mean (a << b) + c, not a << (b + c). This is a mistake of K & R.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I disagree. `a << b + c` should be invalid. Mixing unparenthesised operators is a mistake

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not bad faith. I'd disallow that too. I'd disallow `a - b - c` as well, not all operators form (semi)groups

Comment: @Caleth: the point is not what you would do (such as rejecting centuries of math notation). The point is that K & R made a design mistake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `operator<<` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator&&`, `std::cout << true && false;` is just same as `(std::cout << true) && false;` (i.e. print out `true` firstly, then the returned `std::cout` is converted to `bool`, which is used as operand with `false` for the `operator&&`, the result is discarded at last).

Note that `std::cout` could be converted to `bool` via [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which could be used in [contextual conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) (including as operand of built-in `operator&&`) even it's marked as `explicit`.

> Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

You might specify precedence by adding parentheses.

```
std::cout << (true && false);
```

Answer (score 6):

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `true` is printed and then the return of the `operator<<` (the `std::cout`) is `&&` with the `false`.

```
(std::cout << true) && false; // Equivalent
```